# Cast char* to unsigned int* in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a type defined as `typedef unsigned char uint40[5]` and then I have an array of uint40, say `uint40* payloads`

I was trying to port the following function into a CUDA kernel

```
void aSimpleFunction(int M, uint40* data)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        unsigned int* dataPtr = (unsigned int*)data[i];
        *dataPtr = 2158677232;
        data[i][4] = 1;
    }
}
```

To me it was as simple as but it didn't work. However, using square-brackets to access to each of the elements it does work.

```
__global__ void aSimpleKernel(int M, uint40* data)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + 1;

    // DOESN'T WORK
    unsigned int* dataPtr = (unsigned int*)data[tid];
    *dataPtr = 16976944;
    // WORKS
    /*
    data[threadIdx.x][0] = tid * 1;
    data[threadIdx.x][1] = tid * 2;
    data[threadIdx.x][2] = tid * 3;
    data[threadIdx.x][3] = tid * 4;
    */
    data[threadIdx.x][4] = 2;
}
```

Is it possible to cast a char* into a unsigned int* in a CUDA kernel?

By "didn't work" I mean, it has random numbers instead of what I really expect when printing each of the elements of the uint40* array. Sometimes, the GPU apparently crashes since there is a pop up in windows telling me the gpu restarted successfully.

Comment: Do you mean that `data[tid]` is not a `char[5]` but a `char`? I might be missing something because in the CPU-version it works perfect but then something I'm doing weird when going to GPU. Any advice?

Comment: I think I got confused in the levels of indirection in my original comment. You may want to post MCVE since the error could be in the way `data` is initialized.

Comment: Yeah, I imagined that there was something subtle between GPU and CPU way of accessing stuff. The thing is I want to pack information is as few bites as possible to optimize memory usage. Before I was OK with an `int` but project is changing and need 8 more bits to store other info but we didn't want to go to a bigger type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you're having trouble with a CUDA code, it's a good idea to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  Even if you don't understand the error output, it will be useful for those trying to help you, so I suggest doing that *before* asking for help here.

My attempt to make a complete code out of what you haven shown was like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uint40[5];


void aSimpleFunction(int M, uint40* data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        unsigned int* dataPtr = (unsigned int*)data[i];
        *dataPtr = 0x02020202U;
        data[i][4] = 1;
    }
}

void uint40_print(uint40 &data){

  char *my_data = (char *)&data;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d", my_data[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

__global__ void aSimpleKernel(int M, uint40* data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        unsigned int* dataPtr = (unsigned int*)data[i];
        printf("%p\n", dataPtr);
        *dataPtr = 0x02020202U;
        data[i][4] = 1;
    }
}

int main(){

  uint40 *payloads = (uint40 *)malloc(10000);
  memset(payloads, 0, 10000);
  aSimpleFunction(5, payloads);
  uint40_print(payloads[0]);
  memset(payloads, 0, 10000);
  uint40 *d_payloads;
  cudaMalloc(&d_payloads, 10000);
  aSimpleKernel<<<1,1>>>(5, d_payloads);
  cudaMemcpy(payloads, d_payloads, 10000, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) uint40_print(payloads[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run that code I get output like this:

```
$ ./t1091
22221
00000
$
```

sure enough, the GPU output doesn't match the CPU output.  If I run the code with `cuda-memcheck`, a portion of the output I get looks like this:

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1091
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
22221
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4
=========     at 0x00000080 in /home/bob/misc/t1091.cu:28:aSimpleKernel(int, unsigned char[5]*)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x402500005 is misaligned
```

And this gives a clue to the actual problem.  In effect you are creating a `char` array and then superimposing a 5-byte-wide structure (uint40) on it.  This means that consecutive `uint40` items will start at byte addresses that differ by 5.

When you take one of these addresses and cast it to a `int` or `unsigned int` pointer, you may end up with a misaligned pointer.  CUDA requires all accesses of POD data types to occur on [**naturally aligned** boundaries](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses).  So a 32-bit quantity (e.g. `int`, `float`, etc.) must be accessed on a 4-byte boundary (0, 4, 8, ...).  Many of the 5-byte boundaries for `uint40` (0, 5, 10, ...) don't also fall on 4-byte boundaries, so attempting to access a 4-byte quantity that way is illegal.

One possible solution, for this *particular* usage example, and assuming the pointer you pass to the kernel is a pointer that is returned by `cudaMalloc` (for alignment),  is just to change your typedef:

```
typedef unsigned char uint40[8];
```

This forces every `uint40` item to fall on an 8-byte boundary, which is also a 4-byte boundary.  A side effect of this would be allocating 3 unused bytes out of every 8 allocated.

In your case, you indicated that the `uint40` type was a collection of data, not a single numerical quantity, so it is effectively a data "structure" that happens to occupy 5 bytes per element.  An array of such "structures" would effectively be AoS (array of structures) storage format, and a common transformation on such data for performance is to convert it to an SoA (structure of arrays) storage format.  Therefore another possible approach would be to create two arrays:

```
typedef unsigned char uint40a[4];
typedef unsigned char uint40b[1];
uint40a *data1;
uint40b *data2;
cudaMalloc(&data1, size);
cudaMalloc(&data2, size);
```

and access your data in this fashion.  This will maintain the storage density and almost certainly provide faster access to your data in the GPU as compared to your 5-byte structure.

If there is any doubt from the above, you cannot pick up an arbitrary `char` pointer, cast it to another (larger) datatype, and expect good things to happen.  The pointers you use must be properly aligned for the datatype being referenced.

Comment: I don't see how `typedef unsigned char uint40[8];` helps. The alignment requirement for an array is equal to the alignment requirement for the element type, so an instance of `uint40` could still be be allocated at, say, address `0x1`. If the compiler lets you add an alignment attribute to array declarations that would help. Not sure whether that is allowed, I am only familiar with use of alignment attributes for `struct`.

Comment: I've made a clarifying statement.  I assume that the pointer passed to the kernel is a pointer returned by `cudaMalloc` (and not some modified version of it).  In that case, I fail to see that there is an issue, and my testing shows that it rectifes the misalignment issue, according to `cuda-memcheck` and numerical testing.

Comment: I've updated the sample code in my answer to provide some extra printout.  I'm not sure where you think the issue is.

Comment: I am coming from a "language specification guarantee" angle: Unless things have changed since I last looked (or I am misunderstanding something fundamental), there is no *guarantee* that the CUDA compiler allocates an `unsigned char uint40[8]` on an 8-byte boundary. Your answer seems to assume otherwise. So I fear this may be a case of "happens to work" not "guaranteed to work". To make predefined `struct`s like `float2` align as desired, the compiler uses alignment attributes. I think this is required for any composite type to be aligned stricter than underlying element type.

Comment: I think I get it now. Your answer is based on "assuming the pointer you pass to the kernel is a pointer that is returned by cudaMalloc". That makes it work, and may be easy to do for a simple kernel where one can track where each pointer originated, but it doesn't address the general case, which requires checking alignments, and handling end-cases.

Comment: I agree that you cannot pick up an arbitrary `char` pointer and make it work, even if you overlay some kind of `uint40[8]` structure on it.  I think I said more or less that in my answer.